# How to avoid passing environment variables to puppet agent

Tags: environment-variables, puppet, agent

I am trying to use a 3rd party puppet module which relies on the fact the puppet agent which will run has the JAVA_HOME correctly set.

The JAVA_HOME is required because there is a command defined in a provider (see [here](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/blob/a98184ec9928ebb3a10178356c7d11136649d663/lib/puppet/provider/elasticsearch_plugin/plugin.rb)).

I have 2 options which I can use now:

- Pass the variable when executing the puppet agent (but works only in interactive)
- Put in place a file to be sourced by the user executing puppet with the cron (self managed by puppet)

My question is: is it possible to pass the environment to a provider?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Taking inspiration from the following [post](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/puppet-users/133d4g8bjf/custom-ensure-instead-of-ensurable-in-type-provider)

I created a new type and a provider for it which inside sets the ENV[myvar] = myvalue. Note that the type is not ensurable.
The variable will "leak" and will allow other modules relying on it to work properly.

E.g.

```
### ... Provider code
def ensure
  if value = ENV[resource[:name]]
    value
  else
    :absent
  end
end

def ensure=(new_value)
  if new_value == :absent
    ENV.delete(resource[:name])
  else
    ENV[resource[:name]] = new_value
  end
end

### Usage in puppet code

mytype { 'MYVAR':
  ensure => 'MYVAL',
}
```

Note that puppet will report at each run the value has changed from absent to a specific value. To avoid so, I think it is enough to always return :absent (I must verify that).

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to pass the environment to a provider?

No, Puppet has no mechanism for customizing the environment for external commands on a per-provider basis.  I think you have more options than those you've enumerated, however.  Among them:

- wrap the `puppet` command in a shell script that sets the environment variables you want
- if you are indeed using `cron` to schedule agent runs, then use *`cron`*'s built-in support for setting environment variables for the commands it runs.

The latter seems a promising alternative.

Comment: You can also set the vars in `/etc/environment`, assuming you don't have a need to set multiple `JAVA_HOME` variables on a per user basis.

Comment: Are you sure, @Frap?   To the best of my knowlegde, `/etc/environment` belongs to and is used by (only) PAM, by its `pam_env` module.  Puppet is not PAM-enabled.  My `cron` is PAM-enabled, but it is not configured to use `pam_env`.

Comment: Works for me, see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/375252/what-is-the-best-place-to-setup-system-wide-environment-variables-on-linux

Comment: @Frap, setting up an environment variable for all *users* is different from setting one up for all *processes*.  `/etc/environment` works for login sessions because the appropriate PAM module is configured to be used in the `auth` stage of every authentication mechanism (gdm, system-auth, etc.).  Cron's PAM configuration could be set up the same way, but that would be unusual.  Without that, I'm pretty sure cron jobs don't automatically get environment variables from `/etc/environment`.